# Buffering a New url which is navigated on other page using tosca in run time

Tags: tosca

There is an website called X, When u click on the particular button from website X, it navigates in another tab with new url & i want to buffer that new url at run time. How to do in tosca?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully buffer a URL from IE.  Here's how I did it.

First, I found this article on tricentis: https://support.tricentis.com/community/article.do?number=KB0015575

Following the instructions in that article, I scanned a new module for IE itself by selecting UIA during the scan (in the article).  I captured the editbox of the URL bar as a module element.

Then, in a test case, I just used action-mode Buffer to read and store the URL into a buffer.